# Store checked values with Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have some very simple Vue.js code in a multi-step form. I am trying to store the values temporarily until the user reaches the end of the form.

However, I am getting some errors with a checkbox value binding.

My form looks like the following:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="checkedItems" :value="item.id">
    {{ item.text }}
  </label>
</div>
```

And my Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#multistep-form',
  data: {
    items: [
      {id: 0, text: 'Item 1'}
      {id: 1, text: 'Item 2'}
      {id: 2, text: 'Item 3'}
    ],
    checkedItems: [],
  }
});
```

When I click the items, it is creating empty checkboxes. These get deleted when I uncheck the items as in the attached image.

[image: Not selected]

[image: Two items selected, two blank checkboxes added]

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying array as v-model where it should be one of the indices of array. Try the following:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="checkedItems[index]" :value="item.id">{{ item.text }}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick! Although I don't understand why it would create empty checkboxes.